# How to get "custom range indicator"?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

What is "custom range indicator" in [this video](http://www.wowprogress.com/video/107930-gorefiend-heroic-method-shaman-restoration-pov) and how to get it?

I tried search curse.com for "range" with no luck. Is it a part of some addon?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This functionality is part of the Deadly Boss Mods add on.

The add on will automatically display relevant ranges for each boss but you can setup your own by typing `/range 10` for example; you can replace the 10 with your desired range.

At the moment I cannot remember if being in combat is a requirement for the range finder ui to actually load, if using the aforementioned range command does not bring it up this is likely the case.

Also it is important to note the DBM will only install modules for current expac bosses by default, this means old content bosses will not have any of the auto loaded ranges that I mentioned; old expacs have individualised modules available on curse that will contain these but the manual range finder should function without these modules.

Comment: Could you explain also how to switch it on? I installed dbm, but don't see the indicator.

Comment: I have added a bit more detail with regards to your question,  it has been a long time since i've utilized the manual range finder so that information is currently speculative, I can confirm this later.

Comment: Not sure how you manually load it. But it should automatically appear during any phase of a fight where spreading out is necessary.